# Problemas de segmentación con dobles punteros

Tags: c, punteros, array-bidimensional

Muy buenas a todos, veréis, estoy trabajando con un doble puntero **p para trabajar con una matriz 2D.

En fin, he declarado tanto la memoria del puntero como la memoria para las columnas (dentro del `main`).

```
//Almacenamos cosas
    int filas, columnas;
    printf("Introduce el numero de filas deseado: ");
    scanf("%i", &filas);
    printf("Introduce el numero de columnas deseado: ");
    scanf("%i", &columnas);


    //Asignamos espacio al puntero
    p=(int **)malloc(filas*sizeof(int*));
    for(int i=0; i<filas; i++){

        //Este ya no es puntero porque son los valores enteros de las columnas de cada fila
        *(p+i)=(int *)malloc(columnas*sizeof(int));
    }
```

Por otro lado tengo una función para generar dicha matriz con número aleatorio entre 1 y 10. Esta matriz lleva como parámetros los números de las filas y columnas así como el puntero de la 2D `**p`. Otra función declarada es la que recibe los mismos parámetros, pero devuelve el número mínimo.

```
int calculaminimo(int **matriz, int nFilas, int mColumnas){

    //Alamcenamos el primer número para el menor
    int numMenor = *matriz;

    //Tras el primer número avanzamos al siguiente
    *matriz++;

    //Recorremos
    for(int i=0; i<mColumnas; i++){
        for(int j=1; j<nFilas; j++){
            if(*matriz < numMenor){
                numMenor = *matriz;
            }
            matriz++;
        }
    }
    return numMenor;
}

void inicializamatriz(int **mIni, int nFilas, int mColumnas){
    for(int i=0; i<mColumnas; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<nFilas; j++){

            //EL formato del rnad es para el rango de M a m con su respectivo cast
            *(mIni+i*mColumnas+j) = (rand()%(10-1+1)+1); 
        }
    }
}
```

Bien, los problemas son los siguientes, de los cuales considero que el último sería tan fácil como hacer un cast a un puntero `(int *)(ran...)` pero los otros no los acabo de ver, igual tiene una solución super sencilla que viene de algún problema anterior, o simplemente un cast.

```
minimo.c: In function 'calculaminimo':
minimo.c:14:20: warning: initialization of 'int' from 'int *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     int numMenor = *matriz;
                    ^
minimo.c:22:24: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
             if(*matriz < numMenor){
                        ^
minimo.c:23:26: warning: assignment to 'int' from 'int *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
                 numMenor = *matriz;
                          ^
minimo.c: In function 'inicializamatriz':
minimo.c:36:35: warning: assignment to 'int *' from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
             *(mIni+i*mColumnas+j) = (rand()%(10-1+1)+1);
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: `int numMenor = *matriz;` Eso compila? porque si `matriz` es un puntero a puntero, `*matriz` te estaría retornando la dirección de memoria del primer elemento, no el valor del primer elemento. Eso sería: `**matriz`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si `matriz` es un puntero doble...

```
int calculaminimo(int **matriz, int nFilas, int mColumnas){
//                      ~~~~~~
```

Entonces con `*matriz` obtienes una dirección de memoria. Esta dirección apunta a la primera fila de valores. Es decir, typeof(*matriz)==typeof(int*)`. Sin embargo tu has decidido guardar esa dirección de memoria en un entero:

```
//Alamcenamos el primer número para el menor
int numMenor = *matriz;
```

Y no contento con eso, ahora incrementas el puntero:

```
//Tras el primer número avanzamos al siguiente
*matriz++;
```

¿Qué consigues con esto último? Bueno, asumiendo que el tipo `int*` son 8 bytes en una arquitectura de 64 bits, incrementar este puntero hace que el valor almacenado en dicha variable se vea modificado por `+8`. Esto provoca que, a partir de este momento, los 8 primeros valores de la fila dejen de ser accesibles.

Para recuperar el valor más pequeño necesitas usar dos índices (o dos asteriscos si tu intención es recuperar el valor [0][0]).

Arreglando eso y otros usos incorrectos, la función podría quedar así:

```
int calculaminimo(int **matriz, int nFilas, int mColumnas){

    //Alamcenamos el primer número para el menor
    int numMenor = INT_MAX;

    //Recorremos
    for(int i=0; i<mColumnas; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<nFilas; j++){
            if(matriz[i][j] < numMenor){
                numMenor = *matriz;
            }
        }
    }

    return numMenor;
}
```

`INT_MAX` es una macro definida en la librería `limits.h`. Esta macro devuelve el valor más alto que se puede almacenar en una variable de tipo `int`. Cualquier valor que pueda contener tu matriz será, necesariamente, igual o más pequeño que el valor devuelto por esta macro. Es por eso que es una buena idea utilizarla para calcular el valor mínimo.